# MySQL foreign_key_checks=0 Causes foreign keys to be misnamed

Tags: mysql

There is odd quirk when working with foreign keys in MySQL.

If you `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`, then foreign key constraints will be misnamed when using both the `symbol` and the `index_name` as described in the [relevant section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-foreign-key) of the docs. `index_name` will be used instead of `symbol`.

This example illustrates the expected behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (barId varchar(16));
CREATE TABLE bar (id varchar(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD CONSTRAINT foobar FOREIGN KEY wrong (barId) REFERENCES bar(id);
```

The table `foo` will now have a foreign key relation to the table `bar` on `id`, with the name `foobar`. However, if these statements are preceded by `SET foreign_key_checks=0`, the resulting foreign key constraint will be named `wrong`.

The [docs on foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) don't seem imply this kind of behavior. Does anyone have any idea what may be going on here?

MySQL Version: 5.7.17

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Seems like a new bug, too. It works correctly in 5.5, fails in 5.7.